# Unable to use phantomjs. Error keeps popping up

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

So, I want to execute this piece of code:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1080,800)
browser.get("http://www.ruzzit.com/en-US/Timeline?media=Articles&timeline=Year1&networks=All")
time.sleep(3)

pg_scroll_count = 50

while pg_scroll_count:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(15)
    pg_scroll_count -= 1

titles = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("article_title")
link_class = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("link_read_more_article")
stats = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("ruzzit_statistics_area")
```

But I always get an error while running the code.
I have tried several fixes mentioned on this site but nothing seems to work. [image: Error that pops up.]
[image: Fix 1 mentioned on the site]
[image: Fix 2]
[image: Another Fix which again gives me some error]

The last screenshot is a fix suggested on this site, but that piece of code gives me another error. Please help guys.

Comment: From the screenshots, it looks like you are running IPython/Jupyter. How are you running your Python notebook? You showed screenshots of your path on Windows but the errors show linux paths. I expect there is a gap in the paths on your native systems and on whatever is running your notebook (WSL?)

Comment: I am using Google colab

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IMPPf1e8fIGIyCFzEMp2W1TD3JnFKanM/view?usp=sharing I did that too. The code block runs successfully but then the piece I mentioned in the question gives an error.